# ¿¿Cómo generar una friendly url? en MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

Espero que puedan ayudarme si pueden.

Actualmente cuando consultamos al detalle de un producto, le enviamos el id y en la URL sale algo similar a esto:

```
localhost:60569/Producto/DetalleProducto?codp=1
```

en donde en el controlador la vista está definida así:

```
 public ActionResult DetalleProducto(string codp)
        {

/// codigo etc.
return view()
```

pero deseo que la url me muestre algo como esto:

**localhost:60569/Producto/DetalleProducto/c000000002375-frasco-ceramica-1000-ml**

Como debería hacerlo, me da la impresión que hay que hacer algo en el RouteConfig.

Desde ya, gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, está aquí.

Se tiene que agregar una ruta en routeconfig:

```
 routes.Add("ProductDetails", new SeoFriendlyRoute("products/details/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Products", action = "Details" }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Y seguir los pasos de este link

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/generate-seo-friendly-urls-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Más o menos le vas entendiendo. Si tiene que ver un tanto con el RouteConfig, que si bien te fijas el de default va como:

```
"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

lo cual significa que como tercer parámetro está esperando un objeto (opcional) **llamado** "id".

Entonces, con este concepto, lo que necesitas cambiar es la firma de tu método de acción (action method) para que reciba un objeto **llamado** "id". Algo como:

```
public ActionResult DetalleProducto(string id)
{ ...
```

O si prefieres mantener el parámetro recibido que se **llame** codp, necesitas cambiar o agregar una nueva ruta tipo como:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "codp",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{codp?}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente necesitas especificar el detalle en el atributo ruta, la otra opción es como dice el buen [@KodiakMx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/34674/kodiakmx)

```
[Route("Detalle/{codp}")]    
public ActionResult DetalleProducto(string codp)
{
...
}
```

Esto podría ser accesible desde:

```
https://localhost:60569/Producto/Detalle/c000000002375-frasco-ceramica-1000-ml
```

Comment: gracias por responder, por ejemplo, como le colocaría es nombre a la ruta?   c000000002375-frasco-ceramica-1000-ml

Comment: ¿Lo quieres como enlace directo? Porque si es así, tu pregunta deja de ser válida y tendrías que crear otra.

Comment: disculpa por no ser especifico, pero por ejemplo en este sitio, https://casaideas.cl, yo pincho un producto y la url cambia con el nombre del producto https://casaideas.cl/nuevas-colecciones/5-ideas-para-un-dormitorio. Algo así deseo

Comment: ¿Has intentado el código mostrado?

Comment: Gracias por responder, publique una solución a medias, pero el problema es que se me repite la llamada al metodo dos veces.

Comment: ¿será que llamas 2 veces al mismo controlador y usando el mismo tipo? Por otro lado, ven a la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución, pero el problema es que pasa dos veces por el mismo metodo del controlador.

En routecongfig puse lo siguiente:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "codp",
        url: "Productos/DetalleProducto/{codp}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Productos", action = "DetalleProducto" },
        constraints: new { codp = ".+" });
```

En el controlador esto:

```
  public ActionResult DetalleProducto(string codp)
    {
        String sql;
        try
        {               
            int idCodp = Int32.Parse(codp);
            string nombre_url_producto = "c000000002375-frasco-ceramica-1000-ml";
            Response.Redirect(nombre_url_producto);
            codp = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {

                codp = "14";
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {

            }

        }

        //**************************************

        int temp = 0;
        bool entero = false;
        if (codp == null)
        {
            entero = false;
        }
        else
        {
            entero = int.TryParse(codp, out temp);
            if (codp.IndexOf("-") != -1)
            {
                entero = false;
            }
        }

        if (entero)
        {
            ViewData["titulo"] = "Nombre producto";
            return View();

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
}
```

Pero el problema es que pasa dos veces en el metodo DetalleProducto. ¿Como podría arreglar esto?

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Esta respuesta es de otro escenario, tu pregunta es simple: "¿Cómo generar una friendly url?" 2. Estás preguntando dentro de una respuesta... Lo cual, rompe la lógica de pregunta/respuesta de SOes.

Comment: Edité la pregunta